# ACM 1113 - Multiple Morse Matches

Tags: c++

I'm trying to solve the ACM 1113 (http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=3554) and I think I got a valid solution (at least the output seems to be ok for multiple entries that I've tried), the only problem is my solution is being rejected by the submission system and I don't know why since it doesn't take that long to run on my machine, could anyone please help me?

```
/*
 * Multiple morse matches
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

std::map<char,string> decodeToMorse;

string toMorse(string w){
    string morse = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < w.size(); i++){
        morse = morse + decodeToMorse[w[i]];        
    }
    return morse;
}

int findPossibleTr( string morse, vector<string> dictMorse, vector<string> dictWords, int index){
    int count = 0;  
    for(int i = 0; i < dictMorse.size(); i++){
        if(morse.compare( index, dictMorse[i].size(), dictMorse[i]) == 0){
            //cout<<"Found " << dictWords[i] << " on index "<<index<<endl;
            if(index+dictMorse[i].size()>=morse.size()){
                //cout<<"Adding one for "<< dictWords[i]<<endl;
                count+=1;
                //return 1;
            }else{
                count += findPossibleTr(morse, dictMorse, dictWords, index+dictMorse[i].size());
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}


int main(){
    int ncases;
    cin>>ncases;

    decodeToMorse['A'] = ".-";
    decodeToMorse['B'] = "-...";
    decodeToMorse['C'] = "-.-.";
    decodeToMorse['D'] = "-..";
    decodeToMorse['E'] = ".";
    decodeToMorse['F'] = "..-.";
    decodeToMorse['G'] = "--.";
    decodeToMorse['H'] = "....";
    decodeToMorse['I'] = "..";
    decodeToMorse['J'] = ".---";
    decodeToMorse['K'] = "-.-";
    decodeToMorse['L'] = ".-..";
    decodeToMorse['M'] = "--";
    decodeToMorse['N'] = "-.";
    decodeToMorse['O'] = "---";
    decodeToMorse['P'] = ".--.";
    decodeToMorse['Q'] = "--.-";
    decodeToMorse['R'] = ".-.";
    decodeToMorse['S'] = "...";
    decodeToMorse['T'] = "-";
    decodeToMorse['U'] = "..-";
    decodeToMorse['V'] = "...-";
    decodeToMorse['W'] = ".--";
    decodeToMorse['X'] = "-..-";
    decodeToMorse['Y'] = "-.--";
    decodeToMorse['Z'] = "--..";

    for(int i = 0; i < ncases; i++){
        vector<string> dictMorse;
        vector<string> dictWords;
        string morse;
        cin >> morse;
        int ndict;
        cin >> ndict;
        for(int j = 0; j < ndict; j++){
            string dictw;
            cin >> dictw;
            dictMorse.push_back(toMorse(dictw));
            dictWords.push_back(dictw);
        }
        cout<<findPossibleTr(morse,dictMorse, dictWords,0)<<endl;   
        if(ncases != 1 && i != ncases-1)
            cout<<endl; 
    }


}
```

I've tried the following input:

```
3

.---.-.---...
7
AT
ATC
COS
OS
A
T
C

.---.--.-.-.-.---...-.---.
6
AT
TACK
TICK
ATTACK
DAWN
DUSK

.........
5
E
EE
EEE
EEEE
EEEEE
```

And I get the following output (as expected):

```
5

2

236
```

Only problem is that when I submit it to the judge system it says the algorithm spends more than its maximum time limit (3s). Any ideas?

Comment: Then maybe you have a better machine? Or some endless-loop-bug from unedfined behaviour etc. ...

Comment: It's possible the test case given is not the same as the input given during the "real run" of your program on their server. "The number of words in the dictionary is less than or equal to 10000 and the Morse code string is at most 1000 characters long." Run your program through a profiler and optimize.

Comment: Are you enforcing the "_full matches_" condition?  (I'm not sure from a quick scan of your code, but suspect not).  For instance, I _think_ that a test of `....` and word-list of `EE`, `I` and `S` should, I think, give three matches (`I EE`, `EE I` and `EE EE`) but shouldn't include anything using `S` as that (`...`) would leave a left over dot which can't match any of the dictionary words.

Comment: You'll probably need a fancier algorithm than brute force. I might be wrong, but it looks factorial in the worst case rather than polynomial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm runs out of time because it performs an exhaustive search for all distinct phrases within the dictionary that match the given Morse code. It tries every single possible concatenation of the words in the dictionary.

While this does give the correct answer, it takes time exponential in both the length of the given Morse string and the number of words in the dictionary. The question does actually mention that the number of distinct phrases is at most 2 billion.

Here's a simple test case that demonstrates this behavior:

```
1

... // 1000 dots
2
E
EE
```

The correct answer would be over 1 billion in this case, and an exhaustive search would have to enumerate all of them.

A way to solve this problem would be to use [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization), a [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) technique. The key observation here is that a given suffix of the Morse string will always match the same number of distinct phrases.

Side note: in your original code, you passed `morse`, `dictMorse` and `dictWords` by value to your backtracking function. This results in the string and the two vectors being copied at every invocation of the recursive function, which is unnecessary. You can pass by reference, or (since this is in a competitive programming context where the guidelines of good code architecture can be bent) just declare them in global scope. I opted for the former here:

```
int findPossibleTr( const string &morse, const vector<string> &dictMorse, const vector<string> &dictWords, vector<int> &memo, int index ) {
    if (memo[index] != -1) return memo[index];

    int count = 0;
    /* ... */
    return memo[index] = count;
}
```

And in your initialization:

```
/* ... */
vector<int> memo(morse.size(), -1); // -1 here is a signal that the values are yet unknown
cout << findPossibleTr(morse, dictMorse, dictWords, memo, 0) << endl;
/* ... */
```

This spits out the answer `1318412525` to the above test case almost instantly.

For each of the T test cases, `findPossibleTr` is computed only once for each of the M suffixes of the Morse string. Each computation considers each of the N words once, with the comparison taking time linear in the length K of the word. In general, this takes O(TMNK) time which, depending on the input, might take too long. However, since matches seem to be relatively sparse in Morse code, it should run in time.

A more sophisticated approach would be to make use of a data structure such as a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) to speed up the string matching process, taking O(TMN) time in total.

Another note: it is not actually necessary for `decodeToMorse` to be a `map`. It can simply be an array or a `vector` of 26 strings. The string corresponding to character `c` is then `decodeToMorse[c - 'A']`.

Comment: Thanks Hubert, your solution does works. I'll take a depper look into memoization and dynamic programming, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing up my process for this situation, hope it helps.

1. I would first analyse the algorithm to see if it's fast enough for the problem. For example if the input of n can be as large as 10^6 and the time limit being 1 sec, then an O(n2) algorithm is not going to make it.
2. Then, would test against an input as 'heavy' as possible for the problem statement (max number of test cases with max input length or whatever). If it exceeds the time limit, there might be something in the code that can be optimized to get a lower constant factor. It's possible that after all the hard optimizations it's still not fast enough. In that case I would go back to step #1
3. After making sure the algorithm is ok, I would try to generate random inputs and try a few rounds to see if there're any peculiar cases the algorithm is yet to cover.

Comment: Thanks for the help @techolic, I did found a bug using this, apparently the recursion causes a stack overflow for cases where the input is too long and there are multiple matchs, only problem is that this is not why my code is not working on the judge (this would return a runtime error)

Comment: @Clds Did you actually try a morse of 1000 chars long and a dict of 10k words?:) In which case, the first loop runs for 10k times. Suppose there're 10 matches from the first loop, then the second loop runs 100k times, if again 10 matches found from the second loop, the third would run 1m times, and you have, in the worse case, 1000 / (log 1000 of base 26) = 470 nested loops to run. I haven't done a thorough analysis but I'm seeing challenges to both time and space(recursion with branching can end up using a huge amount of memory).

Answer (score 0):

There are three things I'd suggest doing to improve the performance of this code.

Firstly, all the arguments to `toMorse` and `findPossibleTr` are being passed by value. This will make a copy, which for objects like `std::string` and `std::vector` will be doing memory allocations. This will be quite costly, especially for the recursive calls to `findPossibleTr`. To fix it, change the function declarations to take `const` references, like so:

```
string toMorse(const string& w)
int findPossibleTr( const string& morse, const vector<string>& dictMorse, const vector<string>& dictWords, int index)
```

Secondly, string concatenation in `toMorse` is doing allocations making and throwing away lots of strings. Using a `std::stringstream` will speed that up:

```
#include <sstream>
string toMorse(const string& w){
    stringstream morse;
    for(int i = 0; i < w.size(); i++){
        morse << decodeToMorse[w[i]];
    }
    return morse.str();
}
```

Finally, we can reuse the `vector`s inside the loop in `main`, instead of destructing the old ones and creating new ones each iteration by using `clear()`.

```
// ...
vector<string> dictMorse;
vector<string> dictWords;

for(size_t i = 0; i < ncases; i++){
    dictMorse.clear();
    dictWords.clear();
    string morse;
    cin >> morse;
// ...
```

Putting it all together on my machine gives me a 30% speed up, from 0.006s to 0.004s on your test case. Not too bad. As a bonus, if you are on an Intel platform, [Intel's optimization manual](http://www.intel.co.uk/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf) says that unsigned integers are faster than signed integers, so I've switched all `int`s to `size_t`s, which also fixes up some warnings. The complete code now becomes

```
/*
 * Multiple morse matches
 * Filipe C
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

std::map<char,string> decodeToMorse;

string toMorse(const string& w){
    stringstream morse;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < w.size(); i++){
        morse << decodeToMorse[w[i]];
    }
    return morse.str();
}

size_t findPossibleTr( const string& morse, const vector<string>& dictMorse, const vector<string>& dictWords, size_t index){
    size_t count = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < dictMorse.size(); i++){
        if(morse.compare( index, dictMorse[i].size(), dictMorse[i]) == 0){
            //cout<<"Found " << dictWords[i] << " on index "<<index<<endl;
            if(index+dictMorse[i].size()>=morse.size()){
                //cout<<"Adding one for "<< dictWords[i]<<endl;
                count+=1;
                //return 1;
            }else{
                count += findPossibleTr(morse, dictMorse, dictWords, index+dictMorse[i].size());
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}


int main(){
    size_t ncases;
    cin>>ncases;

    decodeToMorse['A'] = ".-";
    decodeToMorse['B'] = "-...";
    decodeToMorse['C'] = "-.-.";
    decodeToMorse['D'] = "-..";
    decodeToMorse['E'] = ".";
    decodeToMorse['F'] = "..-.";
    decodeToMorse['G'] = "--.";
    decodeToMorse['H'] = "....";
    decodeToMorse['I'] = "..";
    decodeToMorse['J'] = ".---";
    decodeToMorse['K'] = "-.-";
    decodeToMorse['L'] = ".-..";
    decodeToMorse['M'] = "--";
    decodeToMorse['N'] = "-.";
    decodeToMorse['O'] = "---";
    decodeToMorse['P'] = ".--.";
    decodeToMorse['Q'] = "--.-";
    decodeToMorse['R'] = ".-.";
    decodeToMorse['S'] = "...";
    decodeToMorse['T'] = "-";
    decodeToMorse['U'] = "..-";
    decodeToMorse['V'] = "...-";
    decodeToMorse['W'] = ".--";
    decodeToMorse['X'] = "-..-";
    decodeToMorse['Y'] = "-.--";
    decodeToMorse['Z'] = "--..";

    vector<string> dictMorse;
    vector<string> dictWords;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < ncases; i++){
        dictMorse.clear();
        dictWords.clear();
        string morse;
        cin >> morse;
        size_t ndict;
        cin >> ndict;
        for(size_t j = 0; j < ndict; j++){
            string dictw;
            cin >> dictw;
            dictMorse.push_back(toMorse(dictw));
            dictWords.push_back(dictw);
        }
        cout<<findPossibleTr(morse,dictMorse, dictWords,0)<<endl;
        if(ncases != 1 && i != ncases-1)
            cout<<endl;
    }
```

}

Comment: The changes are great Rich but the runtime is still above 3s on the judge system, I think I need to use something different on $findPossibleTr$ other than the recursive function.
Thanks